# Run Linux binary under OS X

Tags: linux, macos, interop, compatibility

Is it possible to create a Linux compatibility layer inside OS X?

Someone have created `xbinary`, which is essentially an OS X port of `binfmt_misc` as a kext, here: http://www.osxbook.com/software/xbinary/. Extending from the idea here, I am guessing if it is possible to create a Linux compatibility layer inside OS X:

- `xbinary` is obviously what makes the kernel accepts ELF. When an ELF is encountered ...
- A port of `ld-linux.so` which itself is a Mach-O binary is started, loading ELF libraries (Mach-O libraries can also be used, to some extent).
- Another kext that catches Linux syscalls (`int 80h` on `x86` and `amd64` systems) and translates them into corresponding OS X syscalls in kernel, or let the `ld-linux.so` replace all syscalls with a small function call in another library that translates them in userland.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would also need to make OS X support Linux *personality* so that the syscalls behave identically to those of Linux (if present)

Other than that a binary might depend on a VDSO shim present in higher randges of address space, which is usually taken care of by `libc` implementation on Linux

Many other subtleties are possible...

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not posssible because mac has a different structure than linux.